# convert byte array to guid using bytebuffer and UUID, byte size has 4

Tags: java, android, arrays, uuid, bytebuffer

I want to convert byte array to Guid. The following link has solved my problem.

[Convert ByteArray to UUID java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408984/convert-bytearray-to-uuid-java)

If the byte size is 8/16 then there is no problem for me. But if the byte size has 4 then I am getting

java.nio.bufferoverflowexception because of 4 bytes. Because bytebuffer getLong() method will read every 8 bytes. How can solve this problem. Any idea?

Thanks
mindus