# Why does Pythons UUID constructor yield a different result to the C# Guid constructor?

Tags: python, c#, type-conversion, uuid, guid

I am trying to write a Python utility to convert from Oracle's RAW byte strings (as strings) to Guids and vice-versa. I am trying to re-use the algorithm from the same utility I built in C#, but constructing a `Guid` and a `UUID` from the same byte array yields different Guid's/UUID's. They are the same aren't they? I've read that UUID is just a better term.

In C# I have a byte array, `byte_array` that looks like this:

```
{byte[16]}
    [0]: 151
    [1]: 163
    [2]: 6
    [3]: 235
    [4]: 224
    [5]: 173
    [6]: 188
    [7]: 79
    [8]: 182
    [9]: 220
    [10]: 222
    [11]: 173
    [12]: 29
    [13]: 103
    [14]: 37
    [15]: 125
```

and in Python I have a byte array that looks like this:

```
array('B', [151, 163, 6, 235, 224, 173, 188, 79, 182, 220, 222, 173, 29, 103, 37, 125])
```

These two arrays clearly have the same content, yet in C#:

```
guid = new Guid(byte_array) -> guid == eb06a397-ade0-4fbc-b6dc-dead1d67257d
```

And in python:

```
guid = uuid.UUID(bytes=byte_array.tostring()) -> guid == 97a306eb-e0ad-bc4f-b6dc-dead1d67257d
```

I see that C#'s `Guid(...)` does some re-arranging of the byte order, while Python's `UUID(...)` leaves the byte order in the UUID the same as in the byte array.

The Python result is incorrect for converting Oracle's RAW byte strings, as my C# code that works (it is in production in hundreds of lines of code), shows the correct `Guid` for a byte array.

Is there any way I get a `UUID/Guid` from a byte array in Python that is the same as a C# `Guid` for the same byte array?

I have looked at the source for the C# `Guid(byte[] bytes)` ctor, and while it is a simple assignment to positions in a `Guid`, the positions in the `Guid` are 11 in number and are of types, `int`, `short`, and `byte`, which I don't have in Python, and I don't want to get into bitwise manipulation to emulate C# types in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to generate a UUID in Java that is identical to that of the one generated in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337638/is-there-any-way-to-generate-a-uuid-in-java-that-is-identical-to-that-of-the-one) Although it's about Java instead of Python, the "endianness" issue appears to be the root of your problem just the same. Take a look at indices 4 and 5 in the formatted output. You have `ade0` vs. `e0ad`.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks, but no. The suggested Java code uses a `ByteBuffer` that I don't have in Python.

Comment: Don't take the answer too literally. The `ByteBuffer` is just one means to that end. The takeaway from that answer is that the byte order of certain parts of the GUID is different depending on big- vs little-endian treatment of those parts.  You have an array. Swap `[4]` with `[5]` and `[6]` with `[7]`, and reverse `[0]` through `[3]`.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this issue as well... Solved it by using the bytes_le parameter in the constructor instead of bytes:

```
uuid.UUID(bytes_le = bytes)
```